# Instance should execute final instructions when python exited terminal closed; these don't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspbian, exit

I have a module that users will import and then access methods *interactively* (learned [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/91872/35753)), which they will run on a Raspberry Pi w/ Raspbian Jessie.

**Method A** uses [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html):

When python is exited via `exit()`, the final steps are executed (evidenced here by a token file save) **But if I close the terminal window**, they are not executed.

```
> from module import A
> a = A(7)
> a.sqrx()
  'hey, x^2 = 49'
> exit()
```

---

**Method B** uses [`context manager`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) which I learned [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/210779/145009):

It **executes the final steps immediately** though the instance still remains available for interactive work.

```
> from module import B
> with B(4) as b:
>     b.sqrx()
  hello, I am B
  hello, __enter__
  'hey, x^2 = 16'
  hello, __exit__
> b.sqrx()
  'hey, x^2 = 16'
```

**Neither does what I would like**, which is to keep the object available for interactive work, but to execute the final steps if I exit python via `exit()` or if I accidentally close the terminal window and close the terminal application.

Is there a way to do all of these?

Here is the abstracted module:

```
import atexit

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x, start_it=False):
        self.x         = int(x)
        atexit.register(self.stop)
        print 'hello, I am A'

    def sqrx(self):
        return "hey, x^2 = {}".format(self.x**2)

    def stop(self):
        fname = 'stop_{}.txt'.format(self.x)
        with open (fname, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.writelines(['stop!\n', self.sqrx()])

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, x, start_it=False):
        self.x         = int(x)
        print 'hello, I am B'

    def sqrx(self):
        return "hey, x^2 = {}".format(self.x**2)

    def stop(self):
        fname = 'stop_{}.txt'.format(self.x)
        with open (fname, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.writelines(['stop!\n', self.sqrx()])

    def __enter__(self):
        print 'hello, __enter__'
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.stop()
```

Comment: If you want to handle a window close, on Unix, you're probably going to need to install a [signal handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) for whatever the relevant signal was. I don't know about Windows.

Comment: Also, you're going to conflict with anyone else trying to configure signal handling.

Comment: @user2357112 the target is Raspberry Pi w/ Raspbian Jessie, I'll have a look at that now, thanks!

Comment: If you are developing new code, you should very serious consider moving to Python 3. You will soon have to, anyway.

Comment: @tripleee for sure, in this case 2.7 is being imposed so I don't have a choice, but I will have to migrate it afterward.

Comment: I don't have any immediate solutions for handling closing the terminal; that might behave the same way a full on crash like power loss would. I'll have to look into it. But FYI for Python 3 compatibility, look at [six](https://six.readthedocs.io/) and [future](https://python-future.org/). I'm not necessarily recommending everything future has to offer, but there are definitely a look of good compatibility tools in it. I'd cut them out once you migrate to 3, but at least you can write code that's 3 ready with it.

Comment: @jpmc26 thanks, yep that's going to be next.

Comment: Might something like `screen` help on the OS level? Accidental terminal closures could be recoverable.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I don't know, what is `screen`?

Comment: [`screen`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen). Often used to have persistent child processes when your login shell dies.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I see now. I'm starting to get the idea that [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54068650/instance-should-execute-final-instructions-when-python-exited-terminal-closed-t?noredirect=1#comment94972208_54068650) sums up the situation, that I'm probably not going to find a way to execute final code before the window closes, and that the only thing to do is to prevent the window from truly closing in some clever way. Thanks!

Comment: (Regarding power loss: there's actually a signal for that too, SIGPWR. It's supposed to be triggered as soon as the system notices power is going down, giving processes a very narrow window to perform emergency handling before things go down. I have no idea what the current state of things is regarding the ability to actually send SIGPWR in a useful time frame or whether anyone actually handles it. Google suggests some systems might interact with the UPS to send it.)

Comment: Now that I've gone back and checked, I believe the signal for a terminal close is SIGHUP. Turning that into a SystemExit or something would probably be how I'd try to handle this, if I had to.